# Как строчку HttpPost переделать в HttpURLConnection?(android)

Tags: android, json

недавно начал изучать работу android с сервером на json и возникла проблема, что не выходит отправить токен. Как я понял с `HttpPost` это реализуется таким образом, но в новой версии SDK этот метод перечеркнут и вместо его надо использовать `HttpURLConnection`, только вот там я не нашел аналогов `addHeader`. Можете подсказать, как это правильно будет реализовать в новой версии студии. Буду благодарен за ваш ответ.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(MainActivity.baseUrl + "messages");
request.addHeader("Authorization","Token " + ClientToken);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection

Comment: `HttpPost.addHeader` == `HttpURLConnection.addRequestProperty`